# Keyboard should always be shown on screen

Tags: iphone, keyboard, xcode-6.2

Keyboard appears only after tapping on the text box of iPhone app. But I need keyboard always appears on a particular screen, when this screen gets the cursor/access.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open like this

```
    -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
    {
        //Add Observer
        [super viewWillAppear:animated];  
        [textField becomeFirstResponder];
    }

And dismiss when your view goes off

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
    {
        //Add Observer
        [super viewWillDisappear:animated];  
        [self.view endEditing:YES];
    }
```

for swift use this method

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated);
    nametxtreg.becomFirstResponder()
}

override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated);
    textView.resignFirstResponder()
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Comment: "-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated" line

Comment: @AmitRaj i hope you are missing somthing because its working my side. So please try to go in depth .

Comment: @Dharambir - I have added the screenshot of the code

Comment: @AmitRaj Please see my answer i hope it will help you.